# large output in common lisp linux terminal

Tags: lisp, terminal, common-lisp

I wrote a clisp program that prints out n sets of x*y random integers.  I'd like to make n=100, but I can't copy and paste the whole thing because my linux terminal doesn't go back far enough, for lack of a better word.

I'd like the simplest way possible to capture 2200 lines of linux terminal readout.

Comment: Can't you just redirect the output to a file using >? For example,

    cl > outputFile

Comment: Done.  Worked.  A little confusing since I have to tab...This definitely is what I wanted to do, but is there a way to redirect a *copy* of the output to the file, while still printing the output in the terminal as well?

Comment: http://ss64.com/bash/tee.html

Answer (score 3):

From Lisp there are various ways to have your output in a file.

- you can have the REPL interaction saved to a file. See the DRIBBLE function.
- you can also enclose your code with WITH-OPEN-FILE.

example:

```
(with-open-file (*standard-output* "/tmp/foo.text" :direction :output)
   (your-print-function-here))
```

Answer (score 3):

Further to the comment above, I use sbcl on the command line to capture output.  Simply load your library and then evaluate what you need.

example:

```
sbcl --noinform --load "compass.lisp" \
                --eval "(print (table-egs (cocomo81)))" \
                --eval "(quit)" > copy.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several different Linux terminal programs.  They all have more or less accessible ways to configure the number of scrollback lines.  I am not on my Linux box right now, but I recall this being in a relatively obvious place under the Preferences menu option for GNOME's terminal, and I would imagine KDE is similar.

I second the recommendation to use shell redirection, though; that's the more generally useful tactic.